Acting in accordance with "a normal life" for the Chosen in MOTW
So we've started playing Monster of the Week, and the Chosen role has the "Dutiful" trait:

Dutiful: When your fate rears its ugly head, and you act in accordance with any of your fate tags (either heroic or doom) then mark experience. If it’s a heroic tag, take +1 forward

Now I currently have a conflicting "normal life" (Heroic) and "no normal life" (Doom). However, both the GM and I are confused as to how I might "act in accordance" with this. I understand that this would be RP primarily, but the concept escapes me.
At this point my only thinking is that I would attempt to achieve a normal life, either for myself or those around me (hiding the truth about monsters, or somehow removing the memory of a horrific event), or accepting that I cannot have a normal life?

It sounds like you need to work out what your character's normal life is or should be like.
You had a normal life, right? You didn't wash downstream in a reed basket and get raised by some shady missionaries? Not that it's wrong if you did, then you've still got some thinking to do about what your normal life is going to look like and how you're going to make it.
Where do you live? What do you do for fun? What regular community things do you get involved with, and how do all those things filter into this destiny of monster fighting in weird ways? They're going to do it, that's what it means for your destiny to involve a normal life.
And the other questions, of course - how can you step away? What do all the normal people involved with you think is going on when you do? If you're part of a team with any kind of institutionality they may have a cover ready for you. If not maybe you've got some kind of freelance calling on the backburner that can cover for you - park ranger, emergency firefighter, a distant relative who regularly suckers you into extreme sports getaways.
Once you've nailed down the kind of normal life you're going to live, then you can start thinking about what it means when your destiny makes your normal life important or tears you away from it.
